# HTTP POST Request using a server proxy in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to do an HTTP post request. My server is running a php script with code here

```
<?
$siteurl = $_REQUEST['address'];
$postdata = '';
$fakeua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0)';

$ch = curl_init($siteurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $fakeua);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

And I'm calling this in my JS like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/server.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      address: urlToPost
    },
    success: function(response) {
        window.console.log(response);
   }
});
```

Is this correct? Should this work? It seems I'm getting a 200 OK from the request, but something isn't right because I'm the website I'm doing a POST request to isn't showing it. I am forming my url through concatenation, which should be fine as long as a I am concatenating it right, right? Or should the paramaters be passed in?

```
urlToPost += "&s=" + sessionID + "&a[0]=" + "Girls" + "&t[0]=" + "Laura" + "&i[0]=" + ts2 + "&o[0]=E" + "&r[0]=" + "&l[0]=" + "&b[0]=Album" + "&n[0]=" + "&m[0]=";
```

Answer (score 1):

Test it out by posting to google and checking that you are getting results. use the `q=` parameter to set a search term.

Also, a 1 second timeout is pretty short.

Comment: Hmm it's just returning  an empty string

Comment: did you check teh php script manually (without ajax)? Did you adjust the timeout? Curl could be quitting before the server has time to send the data.

Comment: Yeah I've changed the timeout to 60 seconds.